# Laravel | Return multiple tables from multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to use Laravel/Lumen Eloquent to chain a few models.

I have a basic datbase setup which contains the following tables:

- customers
- customer_websites
- customer_websites_status

I am trying to get all of the customer details, which I have and then get the website associated which I also have, but then I want to get the website status from the third table.

This is my code currently.

Controller:

```
$customer->with('website')->whereCustomerHash(123456)->first();
```

Customer:

```
public function website()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\CustomerWebsite');
}
```

CustomerWebsite:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\CustomerWebsiteStatus');
}
```

CustomerWebsiteStatus:

```
public function website()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CustomerWebsite');
}
```

The format I want to return is

```
{
  first_name: 'Joe',
  last_name: 'Blogs',
  website: {
      url: 'http://google.com',
      status: 'Status Here.'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run:

```
$myCustomer = $customer->with([
    'website','website.status'
])->whereCustomerHash(123456)->first();
```

Then you can get `$myCustomer->website->status->description` or whatever you have in status table.

Comment: So I did everything right other than msising out the `website.status` ? Do I need what's inside of CustomerWebsiteStatus? I will accept this as correct answer

Comment: I'm not sure how you is your data  design, but the point is that you can chain in lavarel that way, separated by dot. If you need the `CustomerWebsiteStatus` data you do the way I wrote. You can use `dd($myCustomer)` to see and understand the data, for debugging purposes.